# Replace https with anchor tag conditionally Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the below javascript code to replace my content data (http ,https) with anchor tag with class="disableUrl" rel="nofollow"

My code is

```
  content.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
  #URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
  replacePattern = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
  replacedText = content.replace(replacePattern, "<a class='disableUrl' rel='nofollow'>$1</a>")
```

My Sample content is

```
This is the about google http://www.google.com sample. This sample data has images too 
<img src="https://assets/mkmmmm"/>
```

In the above content `http://www.google.com` is getting converted to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="disableUrl" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a>
```

Also its generating the anchor tag for https in src of the image tag too .
Like

`<img src="https://assets/mmm/>` 
 with 
`<img src="<a class='disableUrl' rel='nofollow'>https://assets/mmm</a>" />`
How could i avoid that..

Comment: could you give some more javascript code?

Comment: @ al0ne evenings - Just used the above mentioned code

Comment: Your regex specifies nowhere that it should only match urls that are within an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jQuery, so:

```
$('a').addClass('disableUrl').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
```

Comment: I dont have anchor tag i am generating anchor tags and adding class and rel. But it generates anchor tag for https in src of image tag too..